# ¿Se dice 'poder de vacaciones'?

Tags: modismos, conjugación, pretérito

En el segundo apartado de estos [ejercicios de pretérito simple/pretérito imperfecto](http://pot-pourri.fltr.ucl.ac.be/gra/exercices/verbo/preteritos03/verbos02/exe.cfm?serie=1)  veo:

> 2. Como no <sub>(tener, nosotros)</sub> dinero, el año pasado no <sub>(poder, nosotros)</sub> de vacaciones.

y me parece un eror. ¿Existe verdaderamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. No existe ningún modismo ni expresión de este tipo.

Es claramente un error pues falta el verbo de lo que se puede hacer.

La frase correcta sería:

> Como no *teníamos* dinero, el año pasado no *pudimos **ir*** de vacaciones.

---

Yendo un poco más allá, lo que sí tenemos es la forma *poder de X*, como en *poder de convicción*, para referirnos a la capacidad de alguien para convencer a otros.

Comment: Gracías. Sin embargo mi pregunta no tiene que ver con el tiempo verbal, así que no comprendo la razón porque cambiaste los tags.

Comment: @Mörkö bueno pues porque es claramente un error. Podemos dejar las etiquetas si quieres, pero no serán representativas porque al fin y al cabo estamos analizando un error de escritura en una página web.